# Fit with some complicated function

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I am trying to fit data with a complicated function which consists some special function and I have problem with it. It is formula presented here [(imgur)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLqgL.jpg). To do this I use spicy.optimize.curve. But for simplicity here, I would skip special functions and I want to do a fit with a similiar function. My problem is that I want to fit my data with some functionm which is function of some s, but this s is also hidden in an integral.

Here, just for this post I generated some data with the normal distributions, it is not the good data for my plot, just to run the code. I got an error

```
only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

My code is presented below. Thus, the lambda parameter is the one I want to get from the fit.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import random
from scipy import integrate

def integrand(ξ, s, λ):
    return np.exp(-ξ**2-2*ξ*λ)*np.cos(2*ξ*s)

def curve(s, ξ, λ):
    return s/λ*np.exp(-s**2/λ**2)*integrate.quad(integrand, 0, np.infty, args=(s, λ))[0]

X = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)
Y = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)

X = np.array(X)
Y = np.array(Y)

params, cov = curve_fit(curve, X, Y)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your function "curve" doesn't admit a numpy array or list as an input, but you can vectorize it:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

def integrand(ξ, s, λ):
    return np.exp(-ξ**2-2*ξ*λ)*np.cos(2*ξ*s)

@np.vectorize
def curve(s, λ):
    return s/λ*np.exp(-s**2/λ**2)*integrate.quad(integrand, 0, np.infty, args=(s, λ))[0]

x = np.linspace(0,3, 100)
y = curve(x,1) + np.random.normal(0, 0.005, 100)

params, cov = curve_fit(curve, x, y, p0=[0.3])

plt.scatter(x,y, s=4)
plt.plot(x, curve(x,params[0]))
plt.show()
```

For more elegant ways of vectorizing, try to do your function array compatible, or take a look here:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! But I have a question about parameters. My params here have two values, which are, I guess, ξ and λ respectively. My  ξ should vanished as a result of integration. So, is it still correct?

Comment: @blahblah taking a look, the function curve just not depend in ξ, I edited the code simplifying that. Take a look now.

Comment: thank you very much, but can you explain me what does ```@np.vectorize``` mean? I get an error ```name 'vcurve' is not defined``` and I don't know if this is caused by this @np.vectorize or I just should redefined curve to vcurve?

Comment: Do you know lmfit package? When I try to apply function Model(curve), where Model is from legit, then I got ```varargs '*args' is not supported```. Do you know how can I solve this?

Comment: @blahblah vcurve was just a typo, already corrected, the other thing I don't know i suggest you do another question. np.vectorize just makes your function accepting arrays not only floats, you can check in the link i sent.

Comment: Just to clarify: the documentation states "The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop." The problem is that `quad()` gets `s` as array, which it cannot handle. You can program the loop for `isinstance( s, ( tuple, list, ndarray ) )` yourself.